# Como fazer Update no Linq?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Meu projeto tem o método Delete, só que ele exclui definitivamente o registro da tabela no banco de dados.

Gostaria de ao invés de excluir, alterar o registro da coluna, tenho um campo chamado "Status", esse campo é um Enum com duas opções "Ativado = 0" e "Desativado = 1", por padrão está "Ativado".

Como alterar o método dele para ele alterar ao invés de excluir?

No MySql eu usaria esse comando para alterar:

```
update pessoas set Status = 1 where (Id = 1);
```

No Controller o Delete está assim:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Pessoas pessoas = db.Pessoas.Find(id);
        db.Pessoas.Remove(pessoas);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: LINQ significa Language INtegrated **Query**, portanto não faz sentido usá-lo para fazer uma atualização, já que *query*  é consulta.

Comment: Mas o controller tem Create e Edit. Qual seria o nome correto do que estou querendo fazer?

Comment: Qualquer outra cosia, menos LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que ela tenha dois atributos, nome e idade e você queira atualizar eles:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditConfirmed(int id)
{
    Pessoas pessoas = db.Pessoas.Find(id);
    pessoa.Nome = 'Teste';
    pessoa.Idade = 15;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Bastas atribuir os valores depois de ter feito o Find, e mandar salvar, ele já vai entender que é pra fazer um update

Comment: O comando Set não aceita

Comment: Tenta desta forma, atualizei a reposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Pessoas pessoas = db.Pessoas.Find(id);
    pessoas.Status = Status.Desativado;
    db.Entry(pessoas).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Primeiro ele seleciona a pessoa, depois altera o Status, por fim "informa" que seu estado foi modificado e salva.

Answer (score -1):

O que você pode fazer é alterar normalmente as suas Entities e depois usar o SubmitChanges(), que irá persistir todas as alterações realizadas até aquele momento.